# How can I reduce the execution time of a view?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Here is my query:

```
select count(1) AS `number`,
       `pronexo_pronexo`.`unique_products`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
       `pronexo_pronexo`.`products`.`name` AS `name`
from ( `pronexo_pronexo`.`unique_products`
join `pronexo_pronexo`.`products` 
on((`pronexo_pronexo`.`unique_products`.`product_id` = `pronexo_pronexo`.`products`.`id`)))
where isnull(`pronexo_pronexo`.`unique_products`.`exit_time`)
group by `pronexo_pronexo`.`unique_products`.`product_id`
```

And here is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

Any idea should I create an index on which column(s) to make it faster? It takes about 3 sec to be executed now. By the way the data isn't huge by now.

Comment: general rule of thumb is index your join predicate and anything in the where clause

Comment: Learn to use table alias.  The repeating long table names are really annoying!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  count(1) AS `number`,
        u.`product_id`,
        p.`name`
    from  `pronexo_pronexo`.`unique_products` AS u
    join  `pronexo_pronexo`.`products` AS p
      on  u.`product_id` =  p.`id`
     where  isnull(u.`exit_time`)
    group by  u.`product_id`
```

Change `isnull(u.exit_time)` to `u.exit_time IS NULL`.

Add `INDEX(exit_time, product_id)` to `unique_products`.

In `products`, if `id` is not indexed, index it.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.